# Regex Match multiple keyword search of whole words only

Tags: regex, tableau-desktop

I am struggling with a Tableau calculated field to perform a non-case specific multiple (comma separated) keyword search of two fields.

This works great except for when the subject word is included in another word. For instance an "or" search on "Dell, Aoc" will INCORRECTLY return "Hodell, Baock, Dell, Aoc" where I only want "Dell and AOC." I am thinking I need a word boundary in the ***"Or Filter" calculation*** but I cannot figure out how to do it with the multiple keyword (comma separated) string ***REGEX STRING***.

***Search Terms (Comma Separated)***

User defined Parameter

***REGEX STRING (Calc Field)***

"(" + REGEXP_REPLACE([Search Terms (Comma Separated)], ',', '|') + ")"

***Or Filter (Calc Field)***

REGEXP_MATCH(UPPER([Contractor Name]),UPPER([Regex String (OR)])) OR REGEXP_MATCH(UPPER([Description of Requirement (IDV)]),UPPER([Regex String (OR)]))

***NOTE:*** Also needs to remain *NON-case specific*

Comment: You need the word boundary. Probably just need to concatenate '\b' with the second argument in REGEXP_MATCH

Comment: Can you use the code above and provide an example? Every way I can think of to use /b isn't working.

Comment: Just in case this really is what you did: `\b` (as suggested) is not the same as `/b` (what you said).

Comment: Thank you... sorry, typo... I did use \b... I think I am struggling with where it goes... I assume around the UPPER([Regex String (OR)]) in the "Or filter"? If so, I am not getting the syntex correct at all. As a note, I am EXTREMELY new to this so I may need to be talked to like a 2 year old :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION

Move the UPPER formula to the first part. it was changing \b to \B

***REGEX STRING (calc field)***
"(\b" + REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER([Search Terms (Comma Separated)]), ',', '\b|\b') + "\b)"

***Or Filter (Calc Field) T/F***
REGEXP_MATCH(UPPER([Contractor Name]),[Regex String (OR)]) OR
REGEXP_MATCH(UPPER([Description of Requirement (IDV)]),[Regex String (OR)])

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).